# A selected font doesn't show up in an mail and is replaced by Arial

Tags: css, email, fonts, font-family

So I have this very weird problem I'm not sure how to explain.
I have a twig mail template that has this layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />
</head>

    <body style='font-family: Lato, sans-serif !important; margin: 0;'>
        [some divs and stuff here]
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the font Lato is linked and used in the whole body.
When I test this html file by opening it locally in my browser, the Lato font is used and everything works fine.

[image: html template opened in my browser]

Now, for the real use-case, I send this email from another server, and I was testing it by sending it to my **gmail address**.
Except that when I receive the email in my email box, the police is wrong. I can't even tell which one is used (probably Arial), because when I inspect the text in the mail, this weird thing happens:

[image: local police display from the mail]

As you can see, even locally in my browser, the font displayed when I put my mouth on "Lato" isn't actually Lato. Removing the "sans-serif" indeed makes the police with serif, which isn't even the case in Lato:

[image: local police display from the mail with serif]

Sincerely, I'm not sure what's happening here. The weirdest thing being that I reused a template that displays the Lato font correctly in gmail, and I don't understand the difference.

Do you have any idea what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Custom fonts onl work on certain mail clients, the main reason being the tracking that can be done by loading a font from a server - the same reason images are not loaded by default. I might be wrong but as far as I know, your only option is to use `web-safe fonts`, anything else relies on your email client and the generic fallback fonts

Comment: So that means the google mail client blocks external fonts from their own servers? Also, some other mails I use do display with the correct font in google's mail client, so I don't think they block it on their side.

Comment: In a way, they don't "block" them, they just don't load them

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) and [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to Google directly to display your font does not work well in email since they cannot load from a server like on a website.

I would recommend adding pulling the latin version of the 400 and 700 font weights from the Google font link and declare them in the  of your email .

I do this for my emails and it displays in all email clients that support custom fonts.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap

Example below:

```
/* Font declaration to fix Gmail override */
body, td { font-family: 'Archivo', Arial, sans-serif; }

@media screen {
  /* latin */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v23/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wXiWtFCc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }

  /* latin */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v23/S6u9w4BMUTPHh6UVSwiPGQ3q5d0.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }
}
```

And declare the font as

```
font-family:'Lato',Arial,sans-serif!important;
```